# Export the images shown by microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, bing

Titles says it all.

How can I takes what I see in my WPF map viewer and export it to an image. Any type will do.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Bing Maps [Terms of Use](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html) do not allow to

> 3.2 (b) Copy, store, archive, or create a database of the Content ...

To get an idea of how tile based map rendering works in Bing Maps, Google Maps, or OpenStreetMap, you may start reading [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_Map).

Comment: Damn it... The thing is I can get a good image with the SOAP service, but I don't see the actual route, just the points where there is a new action to take. It's not all bad, but I wish I could've done that